# How to make bullet sizes match in web app vs printed in Google Docs when using a non Arial font?

Tags: google-docs, formatting, pdf, printing

I've come to realize that seemingly only Arial font will print my Google Doc bullets in the correct size. If I use a different font, this happens:

In browser:

[image]

Printed/downloaded to PDF:

[image]

Notice how the printed version has really big bullets. How can I fix or work around this?

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you can change the font of the bullet points (only) to Arial.  There's a long thread about it and the workaround here:  https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/lsU8AMWoc8k/Yc3sd9U72OkJ

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to change the bullet style by right clicking the dots. I managed to find a smaller symbol, although it wasn't a dot.